# How to make a mocked method return a succession of values with a succession of invocations

Tags: mocking, spock

This is such a basic question I'm sure I'll have to delete as a dupe... but I haven't found the answer.

In the test: I thought I'd try something like this. What I'm trying to do is get it to return '333' the first call and '555' the second call.

```
gb.reader = Mock( XMLStreamReader ){
    getAttributeValue( _, _ ) >> [ '333', '555' ]
}
```

In the app code:

```
int id = reader.getAttributeValue( null, 'ID').toInteger()
```

The result:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[333, 555]"
```

First thought that comes to mind: we need a generator. But this is Groovy, not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `>>>`, see the Spock manual, chapter ["returning sequences of values"](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_returning_sequences_of_values).

Comment: Thanks... see my answer, I had just found it (finally).

Comment: Aha, we wrote the answer at the same time exactly. LOL